# Faced with a "floating point exception" error on linux host

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have a very simple c code that will print a string to my linux command line. When i run this program on my host where it is compiled it prints to my CLI. When i move it across to the other linux host it throws an error "Floating Point Exception"

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  printf("My first C program\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Host where it is compiled is

Linux Kali Debian 4.17.8
GCC Version 8.2.0

Host where i am trying to execute

Debian Linux 4.0

Comment: Looks like the other host has another architecture, and the opcodes incidentally perform a division-by-0 (or another arithmetic error like an overflow) there. Otoh, usually the program is not executed at all, if the ELF architecture doesn't match. Summary: You need to tell more about the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities :

- the result of the compilation under Linux Kali Debian 4.17.8 GCC Version 8.2.0 is not compatible with an execution under Debian Linux 4.0
- or even it is compatible when you moved the executable from one host to the other you destructed the binary, for instance you did through ftp in text mode rather than binary mode. You can use *md5sum* on both side to check the executable is the same